# Compiling Wine and its dependencies, to use both without installing

Tags: wine, dependencies, compiling, usb-installation

To compile and use Wine, as instructed here https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine, I still had to install all of its dependencies -- which were many. I wonder if those dependencies could be compiled into a specific directory, such as Wine, so that it doesn't need to be installed either.

The idea is to have a removable directory (pen drive) which I could run Wine from without having to install anything. Since many Linux games do something similar, I wonder if/how it would be possible.

Comment: You can put the compiled executable anywhere you like, including on a pen drive. Make sure it's USB 3.0 if you want it to run at a useful speed. Your launch command must include the complete path to the pen-drive Wine. This seems like a fairly generic Linux question - I'm not sure I see the Ubuntu-specific relevance.

Comment: But how about the wine's dependencies ? Since in all instructions i've found so far the dependencies is aways installed, not compiled together with wine. (yes, its a generic linux question)

Comment: Compile dependencies are different from runtime dependencies. Only runtime dependencies need to be on the pen drive. You will need to tell the system where to find those run-time dependencies, of course, since they won't be in a normal location. You do can usually do that by editing the $PATH environment variable.